# Translating some bit operations from javascript to c# --- if(int & #)

Tags: javascript, c#, type-conversion

So I'm translating some java to c# here is a example bit

```
// bits = 12 bit number
int bits = table[index];

if (bits & 1)
{...}

if (bits & 2)
{...}

if (bits & 3)
{...}

ect
```

the bits & # bit errors because of

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
```

I understand the error, i'm just not sure how to convert the bits & # bit to c# safe code, anyone know how it should be?

Thank you.

Comment: Java != JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just compare the result with 0.

Some `C` based languages treat `0` as false and other values as true. But that is not true for c#

```
if ((bits & 2) !=0 )
```